# spring-boot v2.7.3 jar built from linux does not work well but work ok when being built from windows or docker

Tags: maven-3, spring-boot-maven-plugin

--updated@2022-11-23: I find solution, please see my comment. Sorry to disturb you and thx your attention.

Recently I met a strange issue that same Restful interface has different result when jar being built in different env.

I need clarify that running jar envrionment is my notebook which supports simple Chinese.

Jar built in windows or docker works well, requesting url ""/showChinese" is gotten result of "北京".  But when it is built in centos, same url is gotten result  of "??". For centos jar I move MyWebMvcConfig class outside then move back to re-zip jar. The issue is resolved. I guess some order of zipping jar or env something to cause this issue.

I upgrade spring boot to v2.7.5 but the issue is not resovled.

I want to know why jar built in linux(centos) does not work. Maybe something causes spring auto-configuration not work when packaging in linux.  I appreciate your help me to resolve it!

By the way, The jar is starting well without any error.

I show my code as below:

```java
// this Restful interface code just return Chinese word
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class BillingController 
 

    @GetMapping(path = "/showChinese")
    public Object showChinese() {
        return "北京";
    }


}

// I configured a mvc-config to process string encoding

@Configuration
public class MyWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Autowired
    private Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder;

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        for (HttpMessageConverter hcObj : converters) {
            if (hcObj instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter httpMessageConverter) {
                //to resolve Chinese encoding issue in String
                httpMessageConverter.setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            }

            if (hcObj instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter httpMessageConverter) {
                //to process sensitive info 
                ObjectMapper om = builder.build();
                om.setSerializerFactory(om.getSerializerFactory()
                        .withSerializerModifier(userBeanSerializerModifier()));
                httpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(om);

                //to resolve Chinese encoding issue in jackson
                httpMessageConverter.setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            }
        }

    }

  // ---------------- I remove some unnessary code

}
```

My pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.xxxxxx.console</groupId>
    <artifactId>Biz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>aliyun</id>
            <name>aliyun maven</name>
            <url>http://maven.aliyun.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxxx.console</groupId>
            <artifactId>consoleCommon</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.baomidou</groupId>
            <artifactId>mybatis-plus-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>30.1.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.xxxxxx.console</groupId>
            <artifactId>consoleDict</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.maxmind.geoip2</groupId>
            <artifactId>geoip2</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aliyun</groupId>
            <artifactId>tea-openapi</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.3</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>org.jacoco.agent</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.aliyun</groupId>
                    <artifactId>openapiutil</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.aliyun</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tea-util</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aliyun</groupId>
            <artifactId>dysmsapi20170525</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
                    <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.aliyun</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tea-openapi</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.aliyun.oss</groupId>
            <artifactId>aliyun-sdk-oss</artifactId>
            <version>3.10.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- no more than 2.3.3-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.redisson</groupId>
            <artifactId>redisson</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--jasperreports pdf-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.17.0</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
                    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext-pdfa</artifactId>
            <version>5.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.11</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
             <artifactId>commons-pool2</artifactId>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>enforce-versions</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enforce</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <dependencyConvergence/>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.puppycrawl.tools</groupId>
                        <artifactId>checkstyle</artifactId>
                        <version>10.3.1</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <configuration>
                    <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <consoleOutput>true</consoleOutput>
                    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
                    <linkXRef>false</linkXRef>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>validate</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includesFile>
                        surefire-setting.xml
                    </includesFile>
                    <argLine>
                        --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens java.base/java.math=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED
                        --add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED
                    </argLine>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

My centos version as below

```bash
[root@om console-biz]# cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.10.0-1160.62.1.el7.x86_64 (mockbuild@kbuilder.bsys.centos.org) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-44) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Apr 5 16:57:59 UTC 2022
```

Jdk version is open-jdk 17. Maven version is 3.6.3.

My Dockerfile as below:

```
FROM hub.xxxx.com/test/maven:3-openjdk-17 as builder
ADD . /build/app

RUN cd /build/app && mvn -DskipTests clean package 

FROM hub.xxxx.com/test/openjdk:17

RUN mkdir -p "/cosmos/biz"
COPY --from=builder /build/app/target/consoleBiz-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /cosmos/biz/biz.jar
ENV LANG zh_CN.UTF-8
ENV TZ=Asia/Shanghai
RUN localedef -c -f UTF-8 -i zh_CN zh_CN.utf8 \
    && ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime \
    && echo $TZ > /etc/timezone



WORKDIR /cosmos/biz

RUN cd /cosmos/biz


ENV JAVA_OPTS="-Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -Xmn2048m -Duser.timezone=$TZ -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.math=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.text=ALL-UNNAMED"
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JAVA_OPTS -jar biz.jar --spring.config.import=configserver:http://config-server --spring.profiles.active=istio" ]

``
```

Comment: Today I unconsciously find there is another WebMvcConfigurationSupport class in project posted by other one. You konw in a mvc application  it should be only one mvcSupport. It is case-insensitive in windows but case-sensitive in linux. Maybe class injection order is different between linux and windows when mvn. My re-zipping jar also changes the order. So my solution is just changing both WebMvcConfigurationSupport to WebMvcConfigurer which is interface. There should be more MvcConfigurer in a spring-boot application. Now no matter jar is built from linux or windows, its behavior is same.

Answer (score 0):

First try to add this config to `GetMapping`.

`produces = "application/hal+json;charset=utf8"`

If problem still continues, then download `TraditionalChineseFonts.ttf` and manually put it to `/home/vcap/app/.local/share/fonts/` and `/home/vcap/app/.fonts` in the linux container.

https://github.com/cloudfoundry/java-buildpack/issues/548

Comment: Thank your response. The first way is not the best solution because I have a configuation called MyWebMvcConfig to resolve utf-8 issue. Maybe I describe problem unclearly. The jar built from linux is running in my notebook which supports simple Chinese. I do not think that an enviorment building a spring-boot jar with simple Chinese should need related font.